# Runge-Kutta 4 should be precise for second order polynomial solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The Runge-Kutta fourth order should have a local error of the form $\mathcal{O}(h^5)$. I have a simple problem where the solution is quadratic but the RK4 is not exact. I do not understand why. I expected the method to be exact in that case.

Here is the problem:

Given the initial value problem.
\begin{eqnarray}
      x'(t) =x(t) - t^2 + 1  \quad , \quad 0 \le t \le 2 \quad , \quad  x(0)=1.
\end{eqnarray}
find $x(2)$ in one step of RK4.

We could verify that the exact solution is given by $x(t)=(1+t)^2$ which
is quadratic in $t$.

Following the RK4 algorithm we can find using the step size $h=2$,

\begin{eqnarray}
k1 &=& 2 \\
k2 &=& 3.0 \\
k3 &=& 4.0 \\
k4 &=& 6.0 \\
x(2) &=& 8.333333333333332
\end{eqnarray}

The exact solution is $x(2)=(1+2)^2=9$ and the error is about $9-8.333...=0.666...$
Not exact.

Where is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: The general solution is $x(t)=c e^t + (t+1)^2.$ And this is not a second degree polynomial in $t$. Your special solution has $c=0$.

Comment: @gammatester: Excellent answer  Thanks so much.

Comment: @gammatester: I am not sure anymore. The problem has an initial condition that  makes the solution unique. It is precesily that solution the ones that RK4 finds. In addtion, when finding the precisicion of the method a Taylor series is expanded in terms of the initial value (at $t_0$). For the problem we have, the solution implies $c=0$, so we end up again in $x(t)=(1+t)^2$. Anyway, thank you for your help.